# Переименование файлов С#

Tags: c#

Нам дан путь к папке `C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project1\` 
Надо из этой папки взять все файлы, и переименовать их в таком виде:

```
Afile.png = Afile1.png 
Bfile.png = Bfile2.png
```

И т.д

Comment: а почему так? а не  `project.png = project1.png`, `file.png = file2.png`?

Comment: Это было написано в качестве примера. 
Задача переименовать файлы в цифровом порядке

Comment: порядок не важен и расширение файлов не важно?

Comment: Да, не важен. 
Главное получить список файлов папки
И по списку переименовать файлы

Comment: @Varagian если ответ устраивает, то отметьте ответ как решение вопроса галкой

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если порядок не важен, и расширение любое, то как-то так:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int count = 1;
            IEnumerable<FileInfo> filesToRename = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project1").Select(f => new FileInfo(f));
            foreach (FileInfo file in filesToRename) {
                string newFileName = $@"{Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name)}{count++}{file.Extension}";
                string newFileFullPath = Path.Combine(file.DirectoryName, newFileName);
                File.Move(file.FullName, newFileFullPath);
            }
        }
    }
}
```